# Retrieve data from database based on current user login in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

How to fetch data from database based on current user login? As example, when user login and click the profile bar, it only display his/her data only. I've tried before but it display all data of user.

At personalinfo.php

```
    <?php foreach ($personals as $user):?><?=Html::encode("{$user->username}")?><?php endforeach;?>
    <?php foreach ($personals as $user):?><?=Html::encode("{$user->user_id}")?><?php endforeach;?>
    <?php foreach ($personals as $user):?><?=Html::encode("{$user->email}")?><?php endforeach;?>
```

At controller

```
    public function actionPersonalinfo()
    {
    $query = User::find()->all();
    return $this->render('personalinfo', [
        'personals' => $query
    ]);


    }
```

I think because of $query = User::find()->all();. But I dont know how to replace it so that it will retrieve data based on current user login. I'm very new with yii2. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with :

At personalinfo.php

```
  User Id :    <?php echo $personals->user_id; ?>
  Username:    <?php echo $personals->username; ?>
  Email   :    <?php echo $personals->email; ?>
```

At controller

```
    public function actionPersonalinfo() {
        $query = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);
        return $this->render('personalinfo', [ 'personals' => $query ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohan cause share this knowledge .. It works.. i'm appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve data based on current logged in user. you should add condition on your query.

something like:

`$user = User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);`

also, if you are only need to returns a single Active Record instance, you don't need to loop on your view.

Comment: Thanks for helping me